# Nest change target_tempreture_f : How to use java http PUT to set target temperature of the Nest Thermostat in android code?

Tags: android-networking, nest-api

Nest change target_temperature_f : How to use java http PUT to set the target temperature of the Nest Thermostat by android code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either HttpClient or HttpURLConnection for calling a PUT on the rest API from Android. Here is an example using HttpURLConnection.

Note: It is advised that you cache the Redirect URL per user/access token and reuse it for all subsequent calls for that user.

1. Assume here that the base to start with is https://developer-api.nest.com/
2. If the return code from the urlconnection is a 307 (redirect), then cache the location and use that for issuing  a put request. (Note the cache here indicates a global cache/ concurrentMap of some kind)

   ```
   public static int setThermostatTemperatureF(int temperatureF,
       String base, String thermostatId, String accessToken) throws IOException {
   try {
       String tChangeUrl = String.format("%s/devices/thermostats/%s/target_temperature_f?auth=%s",
               base, thermostatId, accessToken);
       URL url = new URL(tChangeUrl);
       HttpsURLConnection ucon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       ucon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
       ucon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
       ucon.setDoOutput(true);
       // Write the PUT body
       OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(ucon.getOutputStream());
       writer.append(Integer.toString(temperatureF));
       writer.flush();

       int responseCode = ucon.getResponseCode();
       if (responseCode == 307) { // temporary redirect
           // cache the URL for future uses for this User
           String redirectURL = ucon.getHeaderField("Location");
           URI u = new URI(redirectURL);
           StringBuilder baseUrl = new StringBuilder(u.getScheme())
                   .append("://").append(u.getHost());
           if (u.getPort() != 0) {
               baseUrl.append(":").append(u.getPort());
           }
           baseUrl.append("/");
           cache.put(accessToken, baseUrl.toString());
           return setThermostatTemperatureF(temperatureF, baseUrl.toString(), thermostatId, accessToken);
       } else {
           return responseCode;
       }
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return -1;
   ```

   }

Comment: Yup, the problem was for following of the redirection url.  By follow up the redirection the problem solved. Thanks Nagesh.